# How to Behat test for date dependent Symfony command?

Tags: php, symfony, testing, behat

I run a CLI Symfony command that works on last month transactions. It's CLI - I can't just mock the system clock so how do I test this with Behat? It's November, the following scenario will fail in December:

```
  Scenario: Do something with last month transactions
    Given there is a transaction "7ccf7387" for 2020-10
    And there is a transaction "39d7f278" for 2020-10
    When I execute "bin/console billing:last-month" from project root
    Then command should succeed
    And output should contain "Closed 2 transactions"
```

This is current command implementation:

```php
    final class CloseLastMonth extends Command
    {
        /* ... */
    
        protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
        {
            $month = (GregorianCalendar::UTC())->currentMonth()->previous();
            $trxs = $this->bus->dispatch(new GetActiveTrxsByMonthQuery($month));
            foreach ($trxs as $trx) {
                $this->bus->dispatch(new CloseTransactionCommand($trx->id));
            }
            $this->io->success(sprintf('Closed %d transactions', count($trxs)));
    
            return 0;
        }
    
        /* ... */
    }
```

I could force the user to always pass a current month in the command arguments but it's inelegant. New Symfony service that always returns current month is an overkill.

Comment: Why exactly won't that work in december?

Comment: @Nico because the dates in the scenario are for October.

Comment: Ah, silly me..... so, why not insert the fixtures dynamically (such that they are always inserted for the last month based on the execution, and not fixed for Oct 2020)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better [write your own step definition](https://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/guides/2.definitions.html):

```
/**
 * @Given /^There is a transaction "([^"]*)" for last month$/
 */
public function thereIsATransaction(string $transactionId) {}
```

This way you can simply do:

```
Given there is a transaction "7ccf7387" for last month
    And there is a transaction "39d7f278" for last month
```